# Why does inconsistent hueristic cause expansion of repeated nodes in A*?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, a-star

I am aware that we need to follow the triangle inequality for consistent heuristic I.e,

h(n)< c(n,a,n')+ h(n')

My understanding of why it might cause repeated nodes to be expanded is that , suppose we discover a shortest  path from node 'n' to goal node , and suppose we discover another path to node 'n' that covers the same node ,  but has a shorter straight line distance to goal, then we will have to traverse the same node twice (atleast), first to reach the node n and then to reach the same node again to follow the shortest path . So this is why the same node may be  visited again . Is it right or is there some flaw in my understanding?

Thank you!

Comment: Heuristics for A* actually have to fulfill 2 properties. They must be **admissable** (never overestimate, i.e. the actual distance must not be shorter than what the heuristic guessed) and **monotone**, i.e. the triangle inequality holds. Otherwise it simply leads to incorrect results and mayhem. Informally, if triangle inequality doesnt hold and you have `a -> b -> c` while `a -> c` also exists, it might start picking the "shortcut" even though its not actually shorter. Here is an example: https://i.imgur.com/CUlo2yo.png

Comment: thank you for answering , but could you please elaborate on why does inconsistency in heuristic cause us to visit the repeated state again?

Comment: Anything could happen if your heuristic does not follow the requirements. That said, Dijkstra never visits a node again after it has been settled. So as soon as you have settled on a shortest path to a node during the computation, it will not be revisited again - even if the shortest path is actually not really the shortest path due to an incorrect heuristic.

Comment: If you are talking about tentative distances which get improved during the relaxation of edges, this can happen all the time. The amount of how often you re-discover a node (with a better path) of course depends on how good your heuristic is. But this can and will happen in a normal execution of the algorithm, with correct heuristic, frequently as well. That is why Dijkstra has the priority-queue which takes care of that.

Comment: alright   , got it. thanks a lot!!

Comment: so it means that the node with the best path to the goal should be discovered the first time around instead of rediscovering it by a path the covers the same node right? else the same node will be visited twice

Comment: Hypothetically, the best heuristic is equal to the real cost. In which case Dijkstra will exactly visit nodes in the order of the real shortest path and not waste time by revisiting anything else. In practice, you of course dont have a heuristic that tells you the real cost, its a heuristic after all. So even a normal execution of Dijkstra, regardless of heuristic, will revisit nodes multiple times before settling them. In each round, one node is settled - at which point its shortest path is known. But unsettled nodes are revisited and improved all the time.

Comment: The PQ will ensure that, once a node is going to be settled, the best currently known path to it will be picked. Other paths to that node you discovered in the meantime will be thrown away (usually just discarded once they are polled out of the PQ later).

Comment: so in an inconsistent heuristic,  we discover a path to the same node that visits the node twice , even though it has already been settled?

Comment: Btw, up to here everything is classic Dijkstra. The only purpose of the A* extension/modification to Dijkstra is to give it a sense of "goal direction". Normally, Dijkstra explores the shortest paths in all directions equally. So if your shortest path has a cost of 100, Dijkstra, once it found the shortest path, it has also discovered the shortest path to any other node in your graph that is reachable within 100, as a typically useless byproduct. A* gives the algorithm a sense of where the goal is, so that it steers its exploration more in that direction, reducing the so called search-space

Comment: No, that can happen in a normal heuristic as well. Also in normal Dijkstra. It happens all the time. Fact is, once a node has been settled, its shortest path is decided. With an incorrect heuristic, however, it can happen that you later discover an even better, shorter, path to a node which you already settled. So you settled on an incorrect shortest path earlier. Which conflicts the whole idea of Dijkstra, so the algorithm will spit out incorrect results.

Comment: Alright, got it ! Thanks a lot for your time and for helping!!

Comment: While at it, one of the best performing general-purpose heuristics for A* is called **landmarks**, A* with landmarks is usually referred to as **ALT** (stands for A*, Landmarks, Triangle Inequality), which performs quite well. It revolves around the idea of precomputing the real shortest path costs from certain hotspot-nodes (the landmarks) to all other nodes. This knowledge is then exploited in the heuristic to approximate the real distance. As in, "we dont know the real distance, but what if you go from source to that landmark and then to destination, we know that cost already".

Comment: Right , okay sure! Actually I'd been reading Russel Norvig today and they'd said that one of the ways in which A* avoids visiting repeated states is by following the triangle inequality. If you've read this too , could you please explain how that would follow ?

Comment: @Zabuzard Perhaps you might post an answer? I'm not sure if I understand your first comment, and whether you're saying that the triangle inequality (i.e. monotonicity) is required for the correctness of A*? However, this comment thread is already quite long

Comment: @Zabuzard's comment above is incorrect. With both Dijkstra's and A\*+consistent heuristic, once a node is settled (removed from the open set) then we know we've found the shortest path to that node.  However that is not true with A\*+inconsistent heuristic. But that does not mean the heuristic is "incorrect", nor that the algorithm will "spit out incorrect results". It simply means the node may need to be settled multiple times.

Comment: He also made the incorrect statement that A\* heuristics _must_ fulfill two requirements. "Admissible" is the only requirement, but having a heuristic that is _only_ admissible might lead to a slow algorithm (see above comment).  You want it to also be monotone (aka consistent) for speed. A monotone heuristic is necessarily admissible, so you don't need to treat them as separate requirements.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The classic Dijkstra algorithm can not settle a node twice. Once a node is settled, its done. My stuff was kinda based on this assumption. Sure, if you modify the algorithm and allow it to settle a node multiple times (including the consequence of this triggering new discovery of everything behind it), you can achieve a correct algo again - at cost of performance. I think it is unusual though to think about Dijkstra/A* like this, cause its basically one of its core properties that it does not have to revisit a node after settling ever again.

Comment: In particular, the algo is usually terminated once the destination has been settled (which you can not do then anymore).

Comment: @kcsquared I am aware that the comments are long. But I can not post an answer without really having a full and detailed grasp of what OP is even asking. I dont feel confident enough to post an on-spot answer with the question being in that state.

Comment: @Zabuzard I suggest you reread my comment because what you just said agrees with it.  What I'm disagreeing with is that that's _not_ true for A\* when the heuristic is admissible but non-consistent (consistency is recommended, but not required by the algorithm)

Comment: I guess I should probably reframe the question. Why is it that inconsistent heuristics would give an incorrect answer? Is it because it might cause the nodes to be visited more than once ? If so , how does it occur?